# Conversion from swf to html 5 click tag

Tags: google-swiffy

I was trying to upload my swf file to convert it to HTML5, is this the right way to do it:

upload the swf then once done click the view conversion and save it as a html? When I did this, the click tag wasn't embeded.

How do we get about on solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: We need a more details. What do you mean click tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this parameter to your Swiffy file in the URL like

`?clickTAG=http://www.google.com`

or by inserting the following code snippet in the Swiffy output, just before the call to stage.start():

`stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=http://www.google.com");`

Source: http://archive.is/voqj#selection-345.0-367.53